Hugo: Imaging parameter does not apply to page bundles?
I successfully created my website with Hugo, but the images in my posts are way too large (1.3Mb).
I have seen that there is a [imaging] parameter to reduce the quality, so I modified my hugo.toml config file to the following
baseURL = 'http://my_beautiful_site/'
languageCode = 'en-en'
title = 'My Beautiful Site'
theme = 'papermod'

[imaging]
bgColor = '#ffffff'
hint = 'photo'
quality = 1
resampleFilter = 'Box'

However, it does not change the image quality when I build the website, it just copies the initial image in the public folder.
Here are the logs when executing Hugo :
> rm -rf public/
> hugo --gc
....
> hugo
Start building sites … 
hugo v0.134.3-..  BuildDate=2024-09-19T14:28:20Z VendorInfo=snap:0.134.3

WARN  deprecated: .Site.Social was deprecated in Hugo v0.124.0 and will be removed in a future release. Use .Site.Params instead.

                   | EN  
-------------------+-----
  Pages            | 12  
  Paginator pages  |  0  
  Non-page files   |  3  
  Static files     |  0  
  Processed images |  0  
  Aliases          |  2  
  Cleaned          |  0  

Total in 82 ms

My images are considered as Non-page files and there are no Processed images.
My images are in a page bundle, as illustrated from this example from Hugo website :
content/
├── my-post/
│   ├── index.md
│   └── my-image.jpg

Do you know where it might come from ? Do you know if [imaging] parameters apply to page bundle images ?
Thank you in advance for you help,
Hugo

you have to use these image processing features to get it work

Check out this: https://hugocodex.org/blog/resize-all-images/
